# Gridpanel lost filter while paging

Tags: extjs, filter, paging, gridpanel

I have a jsonStore bound to gridpanel with paging toolbar and some custom filter. But everytime when I use paging all filtersettings get lost. How can I keep them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply them to the Store along with the paging params. Otherwise the store doesn't know about these params and they get lost.

Comment: Thank you for your replay,, for store set params as baseparams,,its working fine

Comment: @MNR Nice. But you really need to accept and/or vote correct/helpful answers or one day you want get any. You just need to klick man, it's not that hard, is it?